# How do I customize emacs (with org) into a onenote-like notes management tool?

Tags: org-mode

[image: demo view]

1. shown as above, a notes database is divided into 3 buffers: notebooks, nodes, notes
2. the nodes buffer can only add/remove/rename nodes
3. click a nodes to see the notes inside it
4. each notebook is a single file (such as sqlite)

Comment: This sounds similar to [Jay Dixit's "Emacs for Writers" approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1&v=FtieBc3KptU).

Comment: The question is very broad. This site is pretty much for specific how-do-I Q&A, not for brainstorming or broad what's-possible questions. Consider posing smaller, specific questions that are aspects of what you're looking for.

Comment: Might find something useful in [this setup](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jtydiy/who_needs_github_to_manage_a_project_when_you/) and its discussion.